# Where do I find all the Android marketing graphics?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Apple provides a nice marketing kit with graphics to use in our advertising, I can't seem to find much on the Android side.  I found the green "flat" android figure but I see all of these 3D representations used, etc.  Is there an official "single source" of android marketing graphics for android developers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate some decent images with the Android Asset Studio's Device frame generator:
http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/device-frames.html

License is with friendly Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License

Credits to: [Where do I go for Android Marketing images? An empty tablet image that I can paste my running app in for a promotional graphic would be perfect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343933/where-do-i-go-for-android-marketing-images-an-empty-tablet-image-that-i-can-pas)

Answer (score 1):

[Goodies](http://www.android.com/media/#goodies)

Aside the above goodies and a search for images on Google, I'm afraid I got stuck too in my search. There are some companies who sell their services for marketing your Android apps, but I'm betting that's not what you're looking for. I hope you can find what you're looking for.

Cheers, Wim