# Where do I go for Android Marketing images? An empty tablet image that I can paste my running app in for a promotional graphic would be perfect

Tags: android, vector

Where do I go for Android Marketing images?  An empty tablet image that I can paste my running app in for a promotional graphic would be perfect.  Apple provides these images (basically skins of the different iOS devices) in their marketing resources section.  I have found Android MOBILE device skins at: http://graffletopia.com/stencils/673, yet the same tools are elusive for the tablet population.

I have also located the exact thing I need at: http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?lang=en&search_source=vector_search_form&version=llv1&anyorall=all&safesearch=1&vectors=on&searchterm=tablets, however the cost of participation to download is far too steep.

I need royalty-free images that are preferably also free to obtain but from a known and trusted source.  I do not want to get any viruses downloading files from say: "random-free-image-vectors.com."

Thank you for taking the time to read my inquiry, and I appreciate any tips.

Comment: This question ought to go up on http://android.stackexchange.com/, since there is no programming involved.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the correct forum. I know this will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the device frame generator here:
http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/device-frames.html

Part of Android Asset Studio:
http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I think I marked you as the best answer, Kuffs. Thank you, and let me know if I did not give complete kudos yet. This is a first post on stackexchange for me, and I want to make sure you get credit for answering sincerely.

Comment: No complaints here. Welcome to StackExchange.